# Show Decimals places as default in apex:inputField from OpportunityLineItem to Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity-lineitem

I am trying to get the default value from a customer Opportunity Product field to show up on a Visualforce page.  My VF page has a custom controller.  When I add an Opportunity Product to the page, I want the default value for my Rate__c custom field (which is 0.00) to appear on the VF page. Is there something I need to do in my controller or VF page to have this happen?  It already happens for the UnitPrice field that is on the same VF page.

**VF Controller:**

```
public with sharing class opportunityProductEntryExtension {

public Opportunity theOpp {get;set;}
public String searchString {get;set;}
public opportunityLineItem[] shoppingCart {get;set;}
public priceBookEntry[] AvailableProducts {get;set;}
public Pricebook2 theBook {get;set;}   

public String toSelect {get; set;}
public String toUnselect {get; set;}
public Decimal Total {get;set;}

public Boolean overLimit {get;set;}
public Boolean multipleCurrencies {get; set;}

    private Boolean forcePricebookSelection = false;

    private opportunityLineItem[] forDeletion = new opportunityLineItem[]{};

    public opportunityProductEntryExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        multipleCurrencies = UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization();
            theOpp = [select Id, Pricebook2Id, PriceBook2.Name from Opportunity where Id = :controller.getRecord().Id limit 1];

        shoppingCart = [select Id, Rate__c, Quantity, TotalPrice, UnitPrice, Description, PriceBookEntryId, PriceBookEntry.Name, PriceBookEntry.IsActive, PriceBookEntry.Product2Id, PriceBookEntry.Product2.Name, PriceBookEntry.PriceBook2Id from opportunityLineItem where OpportunityId=:theOpp.Id];

        if(theOpp.Pricebook2Id == null){
            Pricebook2[] activepbs = [select Id, Name from Pricebook2 where isActive = true limit 2];
            if(activepbs.size() == 2){
                forcePricebookSelection = true;
                theBook = new Pricebook2();
            }
            else{
                theBook = activepbs[0];
            }
        }
        else{
            theBook = theOpp.Pricebook2;
        }

        if(!forcePricebookSelection)
            updateAvailableList();
    }

    public void addToShoppingCart(){

        for(PricebookEntry d : AvailableProducts){
            if((String)d.Id==toSelect){
                shoppingCart.add(new opportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=theOpp.Id, PriceBookEntry=d, PriceBookEntryId=d.Id, UnitPrice=d.UnitPrice));
                break;
            }
        }

        updateAvailableList();  
    }

    public PageReference onSave(){
        return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
    }
    public PageReference onCancel(){
        return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
    }
    public PageReference changePricebook(){
        PageReference ref = new PageReference('/oppitm/choosepricebook.jsp');
        ref.getParameters().put('id',theOpp.Id);
        ref.getParameters().put('retURL','/apex/opportunityProductEntry?id=' + theOpp.Id);
        return ref;
    }
}
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:sectionHeader Title="Add {!$ObjectType.Product2.LabelPlural}" subtitle="{!opportunity.Name}"/>
<apex:messages style="color:red"/>

<apex:form >

    <apex:outputPanel id="mainBody">

        <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label">PriceBook: </apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:outputText value="{!theBook.Name}"/>&nbsp;
        <apex:commandLink action="{!changePricebook}" value="change" immediate="true"/><br/>
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!multipleCurrencies}">
            <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label">Currency: </apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:outputText value="{!chosenCurrency}"/><br/>
        </apex:outputPanel><br/>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Selected {!$ObjectType.Product2.LabelPlural}" id="selected">
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!shoppingCart}" var="s">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandLink value="Remove" action="{!removeFromShoppingCart}" reRender="selected,searchResults" immediate="true">
                        <apex:param value="{!s.PriceBookEntryId}" assignTo="{!toUnselect}" name="toUnselect"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.LabelPlural}" value="{!s.PriceBookEntry.Product2.Name}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.Quantity.Label}">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!s.Quantity}" style="width:70px" required="true" onkeyup="refreshTotals();"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.Rate__c.Label}">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!s.Rate__c}" style="width:70px" onkeyup="refreshTotals();"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.UnitPrice.Label}">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!s.UnitPrice}" required="{!IF(s.Port__c == null,TRUE,FALSE)}" style="width:70px" onkeyup="refreshTotals();"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.TotalPrice.Label}">
                <apex:outputText id="tot" value="${0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!(s.Quantity*s.UnitPrice)}"/>
                </apex:outputText> 
                </apex:column> 
        </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: can you add your visualforce and controller code

Comment: OK, I added.  It was rather long which is why I held off adding them.  Thanks.

Comment: remove unnecessary code and put only relevant one

Comment: What's the type of the `Rate__c` field?

Comment: Rate__c is a Number field with 2 decimals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `apex:inputField` it is bit tricky.

you need to wrap javascript function inside `apex:inputField` then on loading on the page if value is blank it will display `0.00`

```
<apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.Rate__c.Label}">
    <apex:inputField value="{!s.Rate__c}" style="width:70px" onkeyup="refreshTotals();" id="rate">
        <script>                           
        document.getElementById('{!$Component.rate}').value = 
     Number(document.getElementById('{!$Component.rate}').value.replace(/,/g, '')).toFixed(2);
    </script>
    </apex:inputField>
</apex:column>
```

Also, you can call javascript onblur function and use this script in case you need decimal places to be shown always.

Comment: It is a currency field, but I also tried the same thing with a number decimal field and it still does not show.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but it didn't work. When you have $Component.rate, does rate need to be the variable API name?

Comment: rate is id of inputField

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I had a typo in one of the lines.  I fixed that and it now works!  Thanks so much!!